# Unicoin Powerups - Guaranteed Answer?

Tags: support, unicoins, april-fools

All the other power-ups seem to be genuine so far for me, but there is one in particular that is bugging me. There is a power-up that will **guarantee** an answer to any of your unanswered questions.

Does this power-up work and if so how does it **guarantee** that your question will get a relevant/and or good answer?

Comment: I haven't tried it,  but it may have something to do with the lack of a guarantee of quality

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227684/somethings-i-dont-understand-about-unicoins-powers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes of course.

But be patient. The experts who answer your question have taken the day off.

Actual answering starts on April 2nd.

Answer (score 7):

For people who are too poor to buy this power-up...

Encouraging

> I am intrigued by your ideas and would like to subscribe to your newsletter.

Helpful

> You should divide the problem into smaller parts and solve each one individually. If you then combine all the small solutions, you have solved the whole problem.

Inspirational

> much problem
>
> very answer
>
> such helpful
>
> many upvote
>
> wow

Wise

> You are really asking the wrong question.
>
> What you should be asking is, “Why does it matter?”
>
> Once you have the answer to this bigger question, enlightenment will follow immediately.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want me to ask, why does the powerup matter or why does my question matter? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6):

Using the latest in unicoin powered AI software Stack Exchange can now automatically answer your questions. For example I wanted a [software recommendation for a physics engine](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/3d-java-physics-library-for-highly-complex-highly-ordered-objects-which-can-coll) but the AI was smarter than that and realised I needed to re-evaluate my life entirely:

> [image]

I cannot conceive of a more helpful answer and consider my unicoins well spent

Answer (score 1):

Guaranted. Yep.
...
......
........
About *relevant*..... Nope. Take this answer for example. I could provide some relevant info by quoting Oded and explaining that powers are still at a beta stage and should be tested to check for any gamebreaking bug or imbalance between player classes they may create. But since I don't need to be relevant, I will instead provide you with a not-so-random haiku :

> Icy rain and snow
>    Nature’s April Fool’s Day prank
>    Winter swapped with spring.